# Redirect all URLs to HTTPS, but force one to HTTP (Apache)

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, https

I have a WordPress Multisite blog which is wholly behind HTTPS.

Now I need to force a single page to HTTP in order to embed an HTTP-only `iframe` (HTTP embeds do not work inside HTTPS pages). With *force* I mean to redirect to HTTP in case the page is being loaded with HTTPS.

The site works fine with HTTPS, but attempting to access the page that should redirect to plain HTTP the server redirects the visitor to the site home.

Here are my current `.htaccess` rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect all to HTTPS if not some-page.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com # Check host as some subdomains are not used with HTTPS.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/some-page(/.*)?
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect some-page to HTTP if HTTPS.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/some-page(/.*)?
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# WordPress below here

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

What I expect those rules to do:

1. If not HTTPS, redirect any page except `some-page.*` in example.com to HTTPS version.
2. If not HTTPS and accessing `some-page.*` don't redirect.
3. If HTTPS and accessing `some-page.*`, redirect to HTTP.

What happens:

1. All pages go to HTTPS as wanted.
2. All requests to `some-page.*` just redirects to `index.php`, meaning all requests to `example.com/some-page` redirect to `example.com/`. This happens with both: HTTP and HTTPS requests. In the end the browser ends up to the `https://example.com/` page.

Additionally:

- My `.htaccess` doesn't contain anything else besides some Xdebug triggering options.
- I tried moving the HTTPS rules below the WordPress rules: they dont trigger at all.
- I moved only the `some-page.*` -> HTTP redirection under the WordPress rules: no effect, other than HTTPS access to `some-page.*` works (doesn't redirect to index).
- Tried switching the HTTP/S rules around: no effect.

All pointers appreciated.

EDIT:

I tried to validate some WordPress stuff for this. For some reason WordPress might be the one doing the redirect. All attempts to access `some-page.*` result in a `wp_redirect` with the site home and status `301` to trigger.

I created the following `if-else` statement to my WordPress configuration file but it has no effect (I presumed that *some* HTTP->HTTPS redirection was happening):

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') {
    define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://example.com' );
    define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://example.com' );
} else {
    define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );
    define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' );
}
```

I also attempted to change my `.htaccess` rules to the following as per some guide I read online:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/some-page
RewriteRule !^some-page.* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/some-page
RewriteRule ^some-page.* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But it didn't seem to change anything.

EDIT 2:

Somehow it seems the `.htaccess` is rewriting `some-page.*` directly to `index.php`. After I debugged and hooked into WordPress' `redirect_canonical()`, it shows nothing related to `some-page.*`. Instead it only shows that it is redirecting `https://example.com/index.php` to `https://example.com/`. This probably explains the earlier `wp_redirect` with `301`.

I tried to check the rewrites with http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/, and it says the rewrites (should) be working as expected.

EDIT 3:

Did some rewrite debugging. It all works fine, but for some reason the one where `some-page.*` should be redirected to non-HTTPS, the server value `%{HTTPS}` is `off` on all rewrite attempts (even when loading the page with HTTPS), essentially making the rule useless. If I remove the HTTPS check, I get a rewrite loop (from HTTPS to HTTP and so on when on `some-page.*` URLs.).

Same result with `SERVER_PORT` rewrite conditional. All requests seem to come as `80`.

When would be an appropriate time to check for the connection port/HTTPS?